# AWS Lambda - sFTP - Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, ftp, ftps

I would like help and or opinion on how to proceed with this Python. The idea is that it is started through an AWS Lambda trigger and takes the new event (file) from S3 and sends it to my sFTP server.

Code:

```
import boto3
import urllib.parse
import os
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

#Info server SFTP GCore
FTP_HOST = 'valueFTPHOST'
FTP_USER = 'valueFTPUSER'
FTP_PWD = 'valueFTPPASS'
FTP_PORT = 2200
FTP_PATH = 'path'

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event and event['Records']:
        for record in event['Records']:
            sourcebucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
            sourcekey = record['s3']['object']['key']
           
            #Download in /tmp/
            filename = os.path.basename(sourcekey)
            download_path = '/tmp/'+ filename
            print("printcaminho", download_path)
            s3.download_file(sourcebucket, sourcekey, download_path)
            print("printcaminho com o arquivo", download_path)
            
            os.chdir("/tmp/")
            with FTP_TLS(FTP_HOST, FTP_PORT, FTP_USER, FTP_PWD) as ftps, open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                 ftps.storbinary(f'STOR {FTP_PATH}{file.name}', file)

            #Cleaning /tmp/
            os.remove(filename)
```

Return:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "2022-08-24T14:16:18.627Z 2eed320e-7e94-4f96-9127-bab6a1ebb1cf Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"
}
```

The code runs without errors but I have the sFTP timeout return.

Any idea how to proceed?

Guys, this is my first question asked here on StackOverFlow. Sorry if I did something wrong. I accept suggestions to improve.

Comment: increase the timeout

Answer (score 1):

If the lambda logging includes the phrase "task timed out" it means the lambda ran longer than the timeout configuration for the function.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-invocation-timeouts/) is some AWS details on troubleshooting timeouts.

To update the timeout, go to the AWS Management Console > Lambda and click your function.  Go to the Configuration Tab > General Configuration.  Click Edit and you'll be able to increase your timeout.  This will increase the cost of your lambda function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came across another problem referring to the lib I'm using. ftplib does not do sftp. So I'm changing my code and my strategy. Once finished I will share the code. Once again, thank you very much for the reply.